# Deeplinking for android 13 without specified host - flutter app

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am trying to add deeplinkg in flutter app, if host is specified, it is working well, assetlinks.json is placed in correct path on host address, and while using adb to check if host works i have response "verified"

```
     <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:host="demo.webside.com" />
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

Sadly we have many clients, so instead of 'demo' i have to use client name, so I have tried with

```
  <data android:host="*.webside.com" />
```

and it is not working, response from adb is 1024, the only way to deal with that is to add manually in apps settings "open by default", but is there any way to do that automatically?